# Java radio button selection and proceed

Tags: java, swing, jradiobutton

I want to have the user to select either one of the choices.
but my code doesnt work. not sure if i got it wrong

```
if (!jRadioMale.isSelected() || !jRadioFemale.isSelected()) {
  JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(rootPane, 
      "Please Select Male or Female", 
      "", 
      JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
} else {
  // Continue to next
}
```

it keeps prompting "Please select male or female" even if one is selected!

Comment: Define "my code doesn't work". That expression makes no sense. Give details.

Comment: it keep prompting Please select male or female even if one of it is selected

Comment: Your condition says to show a prompt if either button is unselected.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @user2822351 : please check my answer..!! you must use AND instead of OR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this ...

```
 if(jRadioMale.isSelected() || jRadioFemale.isSelected()){
    //Continue to next           

            }
    else{
     JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(rootPane, "Please Select Male or Female", "", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);

    }
```

Your code will always show the alert because Your condition returns true if any one of the button is not selected

Comment: Haha, Thank I got confused

Comment: you can continue with your code if you change "||" with  "&&" it will work

Comment: I will continue with your method using ||, this is basically what i wanted to define but, i got confused easily.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you need to get rid of ! , so it will works

```
    if(jRadioMale.isSelected()|| jRadioFemale.isSelected()){                       
                }else{
 JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(rootPane, "Please Select Male or Female", "", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **OR** (will keep prompting, because when one is selected the other IS NOT)

```
if (!jRadioMale.isSelected() || !jRadioFemale.isSelected()) {
```

you really want **AND** (when either is selected)

```
if (!jRadioMale.isSelected() && !jRadioFemale.isSelected()) {
```

or you could use the negation of the **AND**

```
if (!(jRadioMale.isSelected() || jRadioFemale.isSelected())) {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   if (!jRadioMale.isSelected() && !jRadioFemale.isSelected()) {
  JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(rootPane, 
      "Please Select Male or Female", 
      "", 
      JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
} else {
  // Continue to next
}
```

Use **AND** instead of **OR**

Comment: Why do you think this works? Why do you think it is any different?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Elliott Frisch. The problem is in the following code:

!jRadioMale.isSelected() || !jRadioFemale.isSelected()

For this expression, two situations will satisfy:
1.User has selected no radio.
2.User has selected only one radio. In this case, !jRadioMale.isSelected() or !jRadioFemale.isSelected() will be satisfied, which make the total expression is true.

I think you may want to the expression is true only under situation 1. You can modified your code as following:
!jRadioMale.isSelected() && !jRadioFemale.isSelected()

Wish my answer may give you some help.

Comment: thats what my answer is..!!